# Add leading 0 (zero) to month number in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the below DAX formula that is concatenating a month number to a year.
If the month number is less than 10, i want to add a leading zero to it but i'm new to DAX and i can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
Expiry_MonthYear_Sorter = [Expiry_Date].[Year]  & [Expiry_Date].[MonthNo]
```

As an example, if the year is 2018 and the month number is 2, i want the value to be **201802**.

Currently, my formula gives me ***20182***

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `FORMAT` function for this.

```
Expiry_MonthYear_Sorter = FORMAT([Expiry_Date], "YYYYMM")
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the one accepted. OP should consider switching the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for in DAX is an IF statement.

Assuming this is part of a calculated column in your dataset, then something like below is what you are looking for.  Where if your month number is less then 10, then append a 0 between year and month, else just append year and month.

```
Expiry_MonthYear_Sorter  = IF ([Expiry_Date].[MonthNo] < 10 ),
                               [Expiry_Date].[Year]  & "0" &[Expiry_Date].[MonthNo],
                               [Expiry_Date].[Year]  & [Expiry_Date].[MonthNo]
)
```

Comment: This works, but its not immediately clear whats really happening  - the FORMAT function (below) is ideal for this situation.